# Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Office.context.ui.messageParent is not a function

Tags: office-js, office-addins

I'm developing an excel add-in, where few flows involves exchange of data with dialogue.
Using "Office.context.ui.messageParent" for sending the data from child to parent. In few cases following error is getting thrown.

```
Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Office.context.ui.messageParent is not a function
at _callee$ (myscript.js:15)
at tryCatch (runtime.js:63)
at Generator.invoke [as _invoke] (runtime.js:293)
at Generator.next (runtime.js:118)
at asyncGeneratorStep (log.js:59)
at _next (log.js:59)
at log.js:59
at new Promise (<anonymous>)
at HTMLAnchorElement.<anonymous> (log.js:59)
at HTMLAnchorElement.logout (myscript.js:9848)
```

Thanks.

Comment: Please clarify. Is this happening all the time or only intermittently?

Comment: In. one case this is happening consistently in only one case in the excel online. But the same case (dialogue is able. to communicate with parent) in desktop version.

Answer (score 0):

I've developed ann authorisation dialogue which has two types of auth (MS SSO &  manual login).

As part of integrating "Microsoft SSO", added below script to the html which blocked communication to the parent dialogue on click of manual login button which exists on the same page. After removing this able to communicate with parent.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://appsforoffice.microsoft.com/lib/1.1/hosted/office.debug.js"></script>
```

I'm not sure why this broken the functionality. Please reply, if anyone know the answer.